# How to access all links of a particular class on the webpage using PHP

Tags: php

I have around 500 links on my webpage and if the user is not logged in and clicks on them I want to `alert()` him to log-in first.

So I kept all of them in a class **restricted_link** and now if the user is not logged-in I want to modify it as

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="alert('Login Please');">Text For Link</a>
```

Otherwise,

`<a href="link" >Text For Link</a>`

Now ,I really don't know how to cycle through all those links using PHP

Secondly,if there is a better way possible then please suggest that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the next way, basic idea:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function loginStaff () {
<?php
if (!$logedin) {
    echo 'alert("Login Please"); return false;';
}
?>
}
</script>

...................

<a href="/always/original/href" onclick="loginStaff();">Text For Link</a>
```

Comment: :And what will I do with the `href` if the user is logged in?How will I change it to the original values?

Comment: do not change the href, put it for not logged in user the same and for logged in. `return false;` in `loginStaff` function will prevent browser from going to that link if the user is not logged in